# Find some informations about a Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $W=\{(x,y,z):x-2y+z=0\}$
I wanna find:

1. The basis of W
2. Projection of u=(1,1,2) over W
3. The dimension of W
4. The orthogonal complement of W ($W^{\bot}$)
5. The dimension of $W^{\bot}$
6. Basis of $W^{\bot}$

So, I did the following, but not sure about it.

1. Find an L.I. set of solutions for the equation.  That gives me (2,1,0) and (0, 1, -2) $\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $S=\{(2,1,0) ; (0, 1, 2)\}$
2. I don't know how to project a vector over a space.  I thought that I could use one of the basis and project u over each basis.  How should I do it?
3. Since I have only a set of two basis for W, then I think the dim(W)=2.  Am I right?
4. I am not sure either how to do it, but makes sense to me that every vector in $W^{\bot}$ when you do a inner product with a vector in W should result in 0.  So I did $(x,y,z) \cdot (2,1,0)^{\bot}$ and that gave me (-1, 2, z) and $(x,y,z) \cdot (0,-1,2)^{\bot}$ that gave me (x, 2, 1) but then I figured out that this is the answer for item number 6 and would answer the item number 5 since there are two basis and them dim($W^{\bot}$)=2.  So, how should I do it?

Also, what is a Nullspace, Column Space and Row Space in that case?
EDIT
Corrected the second basis.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you made an arithmetic error. For the first vector you're fine, but for the second you get $x-2y+z=0-2-2=-4 \neq 0$.
2. The general formula for the projection onto the span of a collection of vectors is $Px=A(A^T A)^{-1}A^Tx$, where the columns of $A$ are a basis for the space in question. If your basis is orthogonal, then this is equivalent to projecting onto each element of the basis and adding up the result.
3. Correct; your basis for $W$ along with any other basis has two elements.

4-6. Notice that

$$x-2y+z = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

What does this suggest about the orthogonal complement of $W$? (The result being explored in 4-6 is sometimes called the Fundamental Subspaces Theorem, which is a refinement of the rank-nullity theorem.)

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake and the second vector of basis is (0, 1, 2).

But my itens from 4 to 6 is still, to me, an interrogation mark.

Comment: That matrix multiplication is not possible beacause the number of lines from variable matrix is not equals to the number of columns of constant matrix.  But, assuming that what was meant to say was:
\begin{align}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x_{1}^{\bot} & y_{1}^{\bot} & z_{1}^{\bot} 
 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\ -2 \\ 1 
 \end{pmatrix} = 0\\
 x_{1}^{\bot} - 2 y_{1}^{\bot} + z_{1}^{\bot} = 0
\end{align} then this is the equation of the subspace itself.  And is the same equation I used to find the set of basis that spans W.

So, no clue after that.

Comment: I was writing a dot product; I wouldn't write the dot if I meant matrix multiplication. What I meant is that the dot product between any vector and $[1 \quad (-2) \quad 1]^T$ is zero, so the orthogonal complement of $W$ contains the span of $[1 \quad (-2) \quad 1]^T$. Does it contain anything else?

Comment: Thanks again, Ian.  And I am sorry if you may have took wrongly what I wrote regarding matrix multiplication.  That is a situation that texted messages my produce.  Glad we could understand each other about that topic.

But I still not understand that.  What you are saying is that $W^{\bot} = (1, -2, 1)^{T}$? And also that the Set of Basis would be the same as the set of Basis of W except that the vectors are transposed in $S^{\bot}$?

Comment: We have $(1,-2,1)^T \in W^{\perp}$ by a calculation, and since $W^{\perp}$ is a subspace, it contains the span of $(1,-2,1)^T$. $W^{\perp}$ contains nothing else. You can see this in several ways; one is that if the dimension of $W^{\perp}$ were greater than 1 then the dimension of $W$ would be less than 2. So $\{ (1,-2,1)^T \}$ is a basis for $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: Also, there's no transposing going on with orthogonal complements; the elements of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ are from the same space.